# Get time difference between two times in swift 3

Tags: swift3, nstimeinterval

I have 2 variables where I get 2 times from datePicker and I need to save on a variable the difference between them.

```
    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "HHmm"

    time2 = timeFormatter.date(from: timeFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date))!
```

I have tried to get the timeIntervalSince1970 from both of them and them substract them and get the difference on milliseconds which I will turn back to hours and minutes, but I get a very big number which doesn't corresponds to the actual time.

```
let dateTest = time2.timeIntervalSince1970 - time1.timeIntervalSince1970
```

Then I have tried using time2.timeIntervalSince(date: time1), but again the result milliseconds are much much more than the actual time.

How I can get the correct time difference between 2 times and have the result as hours and minutes in format "0823" for 8 hours and 23 minutes?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The recommended way to do any date math is `Calendar` and `DateComponents`

```
let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: time1, to: time2)
let formattedString = String(format: "%02ld%02ld", difference.hour!, difference.minute!)
print(formattedString)
```

The format `%02ld` adds the padding zero.

If you need a standard format with a colon between hours and minutes `DateComponentsFormatter()` could be a more convenient way

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]
print(formatter.string(from: time1, to: time2)!)
```

Comment: According to your code `time1` and `time2` are supposed to be `Date` instances. A date formatter is not needed.

Comment: When I does this with code I get following as printout which is not correct: "fallAsleep: 2017-12-25 21:51:49 +0000, WakeUp: 2017-12-25 06:49:55 +0000, Difference: 1501"

Comment: But i just noticed that the mistake is because it calculates the same day.

Comment: If you are using dates without the day component add one day to `wake` if `wake` < `sleep`

Comment: ok, I have added  `if timePicker.date <= fallAsleep {
            timePicker.date = timePicker.date.addingTimeInterval(+86400)
        }` and I am adding 24 hours on the second date to handle the day difference.

Answer (score 20):

`TimeInterval` measures seconds, not milliseconds:

```
let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 12600) // 3:30

let diff = Int(date2.timeIntervalSince1970 - date1.timeIntervalSince1970)

let hours = diff / 3600
let minutes = (diff - hours * 3600) / 60
```

Comment: why are using `12600` on this line `let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 12600)` ?

Comment: That's just an example.

Answer (score 9):

To get duration in **seconds** between two time intervals, this can be used -

```
let time1 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: startTime)
let time2 = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: endTime)
let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.second], from: time1, to: time2)
let duration = difference.second
```

Answer (score 8):

Now you can do it in swift 5 this way,

```
func getDateDiff(start: Date, end: Date) -> Int  {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([Calendar.Component.second], from: start, to: end)

    let seconds = dateComponents.second
    return Int(seconds!)
}
```

Comment: Which module do I have to import here? I always get the error ```Use of undeclared type 'Seconds'```

Comment: @linus_hologram you can just replace it with Int